Flutter in_app_purchase_storekit Unable to encode userInfo of type _NSInlineData
I am using in_app_purchase: ^3.2.0 package for implementing a premium subscription feature to users, I am managing the purchase updates on Bloc to communicate with ui.
(fyi still on progress)
For testing purpose I am using StoreKit. I am successfully able to fetch products, buy and verify them. But I am having problems on restoring purchases.
My service code:
class PaymentService {
  final InAppPurchase inAppPurchase;
  List<ProductDetails> products = [];
  List<PurchaseDetails> purchases = [];
  bool isAvailable = false;
  bool purchasePending = false;
  bool isProUser = false;
  StreamSubscription<List<PurchaseDetails>>? subscription;
  final StreamController<PaymentServiceEvent> serviceController =
      StreamController.broadcast();

  PaymentService({required this.inAppPurchase}) {
    initStoreInfo();
  }

  Stream<PaymentServiceEvent> get serviceUpdates => serviceController.stream;

  Future<void> initStoreInfo() async {
    isAvailable = await inAppPurchase.isAvailable();
    if (!isAvailable) {
      _addErrorToStream('Store is not available');
      return;
    }

    await _fetchAndLoadProducts();
    listenToPurchaseUpdated();
  }

  Future<void> _fetchAndLoadProducts() async {
    Set<String> ids = {
      '1_week_subscription',
      '1_month_subscription',
    };
    final response = await inAppPurchase.queryProductDetails(ids);
    if (response.error != null) {
      _addErrorToStream(response.error!.message);
    } else if (response.productDetails.isEmpty) {
      _addErrorToStream('No products found');
    } else {
      products = response.productDetails;
      serviceController.add(PaymentServiceEvent.productsLoaded(products));
    }
  }

  void listenToPurchaseUpdated() {
    subscription = inAppPurchase.purchaseStream.listen((purchaseDetailsList) {
      purchases.addAll(purchaseDetailsList);
      for (var purchase in purchaseDetailsList) {
        _handlePurchaseUpdate(purchase);
      }
    }, onDone: () {
      logger.d('Purchase stream subscription done');
      subscription?.cancel();
    }, onError: (error) {
      logger.d('Subscription error: $error');
      _addErrorToStream(error.toString());
    });
  }

  void _handlePurchaseUpdate(PurchaseDetails purchase) async {
    if (purchase.pendingCompletePurchase) {
      logger.d('Completing purchase: ${purchase.productID}');
      await inAppPurchase.completePurchase(purchase);
    }
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
        purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
      _verifyPurchase(purchase);
    } else if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.error) {
      logger.d('Error in purchasing: ${purchase.error}');
    }
  }

  void _verifyPurchase(PurchaseDetails purchase) {
    if (purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.purchased ||
        purchase.status == PurchaseStatus.restored) {
      isProUser = true;
      serviceController.add(PaymentServiceEvent.purchaseVerified(purchase));
    }
  }

    Future<bool> buyProduct(ProductDetails productDetails) async {
    try {
      return await inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(
          purchaseParam: PurchaseParam(productDetails: productDetails));
    } catch (e) {
      logger.d("Error buying product: $e");
      return false;
    }
  }

  Future<void> restorePurchases() async {
    try {
      await inAppPurchase.restorePurchases();
    } catch (e) {
      logger.d('Error restoring purchases: $e');
      if (e is SKError) {
        logger.d('SKError code: ${e.code} message: ${e.userInfo.toString()}');
      }
      logger.d('Platform: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }

  void _addErrorToStream(String error) {
    logger.d('Error: $error');
    serviceController.add(PaymentServiceEvent.error(error));
  }

  void dispose() {
    serviceController.close();
    subscription?.cancel();
  }
}

class PaymentServiceEvent {
  final List<ProductDetails>? products;
  final PurchaseDetails? purchaseDetails;
  final String? error;

  PaymentServiceEvent._({this.products, this.purchaseDetails, this.error});

  factory PaymentServiceEvent.productsLoaded(List<ProductDetails> products) =>
      PaymentServiceEvent._(products: products);
  factory PaymentServiceEvent.purchaseVerified(
          PurchaseDetails purchaseDetails) =>
      PaymentServiceEvent._(purchaseDetails: purchaseDetails);
  factory PaymentServiceEvent.error(String error) =>
      PaymentServiceEvent._(error: error);
}


Bloc Implementation

class PaymentBloc extends Bloc<PaymentEvent, PaymentState> {
  final PaymentService paymentService;
  final SubscriptionRepository subscriptionRepository;
  late final StreamSubscription _paymentServiceSubscription;

  PaymentBloc(
    this.paymentService,
    this.subscriptionRepository,
  ) : super(PaymentInitialState()) {
    on<LoadProductsEvent>(_onLoadProducts);
    on<BuyProductEvent>(_onBuyProduct);
    on<RestorePurchasesEvent>(_onRestorePurchases);
    on<PurchaseVerifiedEvent>(_onPurchaseVerified);
    on<SubscriptionUpdatedEvent>(_onSubscriptionUpdated);

    _paymentServiceSubscription = paymentService.serviceUpdates
        .listen(_handleServiceUpdate, onError: _handleError);
  }

  void _handleServiceUpdate(PaymentServiceEvent event) {
    if (event.products != null) {
      add(LoadProductsEvent());
    } else if (event.purchaseDetails != null) {
      add(PurchaseVerifiedEvent(event.purchaseDetails!));
    } else if (event.error != null) {
      add(PaymentEventError(event.error!));
    }
  }

  void _handleError(Object error) {
    add(PaymentEventError(error.toString()));
  }

  Future<void> _onLoadProducts(
      LoadProductsEvent event, Emitter<PaymentState> emit) async {
    emit(LoadingProductsState());
    try {
      if (paymentService.products.isNotEmpty) {
        emit(LoadProductsSuccessEvent(paymentService.products));
      } else {
        emit(PaymentFailureState('No products available for purchase'));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      emit(PaymentFailureState(error.toString()));
    }
  }

  Future<void> _onBuyProduct(
      BuyProductEvent event, Emitter<PaymentState> emit) async {
    emit(PaymentRequestedState(event.product));
    try {
      bool success = await paymentService.buyProduct(event.product);
      if (success) {
        emit(PaymentSuccessState(event.product));
      } else {
        emit(PaymentFailureState(
            "Purchase failed or user is already a pro user."));
      }
    } catch (error) {
      emit(PaymentFailureState(error.toString()));
    }
  }

  FutureOr<void> _onPurchaseVerified(
      PurchaseVerifiedEvent event, Emitter<PaymentState> emit) {
    // subscriptionRepository.subscribePremium(
    //     subscription: event.purchaseDetails);
    emit(PurchaseVerifiedState(event.purchaseDetails));
  }

  Future<void> _onRestorePurchases(
      RestorePurchasesEvent event, Emitter<PaymentState> emit) async {
    emit(PaymentPendingState());
    try {
      await paymentService.restorePurchases();
      emit(PurchaseRestored());
    } catch (error) {
      emit(PaymentFailureState(error.toString()));
    }
  }

  void _onSubscriptionUpdated(
      SubscriptionUpdatedEvent event, Emitter<PaymentState> emit) {
    emit(SubscriptionUpdatedState(event.subscriptionId, event.status));
  }

  @override
  Future<void> close() {
    _paymentServiceSubscription.cancel();
    paymentService.dispose();
    return super.close();
  }
}


So when I call paymentService.restorePurchases() method it throws this error:
{
  "SKError": {
    "code": -1005,
    "message": {
      "NSLocalizedDescription": "The network connection was lost.",
      "NSUnderlyingError": {
        "domain": "kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork",
        "userInfo": {
          "NSErrorPeerAddressKey": "Unable to encode native userInfo object of type _NSInlineData to map. Please submit an issue at https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new with the title \"[in_app_purchase_storekit] Unable to encode userInfo of type _NSInlineData\" and add reproduction steps and the error details in the description field.",
          "_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey": -4,
          "_kCFStreamErrorDomainKey": 4
        },
        "code": -1005
      }
    }
  }
}


